# Struggling for Backbone syntax in collection events

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a collection, I can do this successfully ('this' is the collection instance):

```
this.on('change:username', function(model,property,something){

  // model is backbone model that changed
  // property is the property that changed (username in this case)
  // something is some empty mystery object that I can't identify

}
```

however what I want to do is this:

```
this.on('change', function(model,property,something){

  // model is backbone model that changed
  // ***how can I read the properties that changed here?***
  // something is some empty mystery object that I can't identify

}
```

the problem is that in the second case, I can't get the property that changed...maybe that's because it's potentially multiple property changes all at once.

How can I capture that properties that changed in the second case? is this possible?

The only way I know how to do this would be

```
  this.on('change', function(model, something){

      // something object is unidentifiable

     var changed = model.changed;  //hash of changed attributes

    }
```

so my other question is: what is that mystery object "something"? It is just an empty object...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of options you can use in general change events:

1. [Backbone.Model#hasChanged](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-hasChanged): This will allow you to see if a model attribute has changed in the context of this change event. If so, you can get its new value and apply it to the view (or whatever other context) as needed.
2. [Backbone.Model#changedAttributes](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-changedAttributes): This will allow you to get all changed attributes since the last `set()` call. When called with no parameters, it is a defensively cloned copy of the `changed` hash; you can also pass in a hash of parameters and get only what is different about the model relative to that set of key/value pairs.
3. [Backbone.Model#previous](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-previous): This will allow you to get the previous value of a model attribute during a change event.
4. [Backbone.Model#previousAttributes](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-previousAttributes): This will allow you to get all the previous values of a model during a change event. You could use this to completely undo a change (by calling `set` with the result of this function) if you wanted to.

By the way, the third parameter of the `change:attr` event (and the second of `change`) is an options object, which can be useful if you want to specify custom values that can be read by your event handlers. There are also a number of standard options Backbone will handle specially. See the documentation for [Backbone.Model#set](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set) for more information on the specific options, and take a look at the [Backbone event list](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog) to see the callback signatures expected when those events are triggered.